# Function template type deduction at runtime

Tags: c++, function, templates, runtime, compile-time

I am trying to understand why the following compiles/runs despite the template type being resolved at run time. Is it because the `if/else` calls to `f` alone are enough to tell the compiler to create `void f<double>(double)` and `void f<std::string>(std::string)`?

**test.hpp**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T x) {
    if(std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
        std::cout << "String: " << x;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"

int main(int, char** argv) {
    double x(std::stod(argv[1]));

    if(x < 42) f(x);
    else f(std::to_string(x));

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ (clan)g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp
$ ./a.exe 41

$ ./a.exe 43
String: 43.000000
```

Comment: Code is generated for both the if and else branches. At runtime, the appropriate branch is run depending on the value of `x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no run time template deduction going on here.  When you have

```
if(x < 42) f(x);
```

The compiler knows, at compile time, that `x` is a double so it stamps out

```
void f<double>(double)
```

Then in

```
else f(std::to_string(x));
```

The compiler knows the return type of `std::to_string` is a `std::string` so it stamps out a

```
void f<std::string>(std::string)
```

To use.  Both functions exist at the same time and only one gets called at run time depending on what input you give the program.

Lets look at [this example code](https://godbolt.org/g/p2oF34) provided by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656772/function-template-type-deduction-at-runtime/43656864?noredirect=1#comment74361669_43656864).  Using

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
__attribute__((used)) int f(T x) {
    if(std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc > 1) return f(1);
    else return f(1.0);
}
```

Compiling with `-O3 -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` generates the assembly

```
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     edi, 2
        setl    al
        inc     eax
        ret

int f<int>(int):                        # @int f<int>(int)
        mov     eax, 1
        ret

int f<double>(double):                  # @int f<double>(double)
        mov     eax, 2
        ret
```

As you can see both template functions exist in the assembly and it is just the `if` in main that decides which one to call at run time.

Comment: For illustration purposes, you can look at the assembly of an example without the bloat of `<iostream>` and `<string>`: https://godbolt.org/g/p2oF34

Comment: @chris Nice little example.  Mind if I add that to my answer to show it off some?

Answer (score 1):

1. Compiler reads `main`, sees two calls to `f`, once with a string argument and once with an int
2. Generates two `f`s. Calls to both functions are embedded in main.
3. Your if statement causes one or another call.
   So there is no template resolution in runtime. Such thing does not exist.